# Accessing individual objects in a Django template file

Tags: python, django

I am editing a template to display an attribute of the first member in a list. I am trying to access it like so:

```
{{ food_list.index(0).id }}
```

I get an error that says `Could not parse the remainder: '(0).id'`.
What is the correct way to access an individual member in a list?

Answer (score 3):

```
{{ food_list.0.id }}
```

Alternatively,

```
{% with f=food_list|first %}
  {{ f.id }}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call methods in a template. Either write a template tag for this, or do it in your view. If what you wanted to do was just index the list, then you don't use the `index()` method for that; just use [normal dot notation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables) instead.